# Excel 365 recover information box always pops up

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365, popups

I've been using Excel 365 for several months now and as of last week I have this box pop up every few minutes randomly it also happens when I open, close, and save sheets.

[image: this is the box that pops up]

It is not harming my data in any way that I know about. but it is starting to annoy me.
I have tried the internet office 365 repair tool and it has not fixed my issue.
Have any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: Are you storing the file locally or in the cloud?

Comment: All my files are local.

Answer (score 0):

Review what updates were installed when you started to see the failure.  While Office updates are "streamed" to you - other updates to the OS and .NET framework can have a negative affect on Office.

Also check for other installed applications/updates for things like PDF readers and such that may interact with office.

If this only happens when you open certain excel files - those files could have issues.  Even if data looks correct, try opening a blank workbook and copy data over to see if that resolves your issue.  You could also try to replicate this on another machine to see if happens to them as well.

You can also try to open Excel in safe mode - you have to find where the executable is (not the short cut) - usually under "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\"  hold CTRL key down and then double click on the Excel.exe file. You will get prompted to open Excel in safe mode.  If you do this and it works - then you have a bad add-in that you need to find and disable.